# Why does my ({$exists: true}) query take this long?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection with 200 million documents.

I've added an index on the id field which is a string field using collection.createIndex({id: 1})

The query db.collection.countDocuments(); takes a couple of seconds and returns the actual count of 207.713.493.

The query db.collection.countDocuments({id: {$exists: false}}); finishes instantly and returns 0 (as expected).

However, the query db.collection.countDocuments({id: {$exists: true}}); takes forever to finish. Right now it has been running for 8 hours and it is not returning.

How could this be the case? The result should be pretty easy to obtain since it should be equal to the total count.

Comment: The query still needs to count the documents. The condition with false returned immediately as the query filter returned very little or no documents based upon the index. There is a concept called as Query Selectivity - this is about how few documents can be retrieved with a query when using an index. If your query returns less than 10% for example, its okay selectivity. If the query returns 1%, its very good selectivity. If your query returns 90%, its a bad selectivity and the index is of not of much use - other than occupying disk space and memory.

Answer (score 0):

According [to this AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html) documentation:

> Amazon DocumentDB does not currently support the ability to use indexes with the $ne, $nin, $nor, $not, $exists, $distinct, and $elemMatch operators. As a result, utilizing these operators will result in collection scans.

This means every Document needs scanning to perform the count.

This differs to MongoDB, which **does** allow the indexing of these operators.

In example, on DocumentDB

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$exists: true}}).explain('executionStats')
```

returns

```
winningPlan: { stage: 'COLLSCAN' }
```

whereas on MongoDB it returns (much faster):

```
winningPlan: { stage: 'IXSCAN' }
```